# Setting vector area

Tags: qgis, nearest-neighbor

I'm new to QGIS and am using it to spatially analyze the placements of artifacts within an excavated site. I am trying to conduct nearest neighbour analysis; however, I do not know how to set the area of interest for this test as the site (ie. the excavation grid). Therefore, I am getting a lower NNI than I would expect because the test is only using the bounded box of the artifacts as the area of interest.

Comment: QGis does not allow to set the area parameter. If you can have acces to an installation of ArcMap, you can do it there. Or, not the most elegant, since in the report you have the mean observed distance, you can manually calculate the expected mean distance, and the calculate the index. I am not a programer, but I think it could be a nice feature fo the NNA algorithm in Qgis